# How to use parameters from Uri in destination App?

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I need to launch an app with a boolean parameter from another app that gets such parameter. Both are apps installed in Windows. The purpose of the parameter is to enable/disable a control in the launched app.

I found a way to launch the app with the parameter (being the parameter like `"?MyParameter=true"`). I'm using `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(myUriWithParameters);` in app A, and it fires successfully, but don't have any idea how to get that parameter from the new app. Is this possible? how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> The [`OnActivated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Application#Windows_UI_Xaml_Application_OnActivated_Windows_ApplicationModel_Activation_IActivatedEventArgs_) event [handler receives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation#step-3-handle-the-activated-event) all activation events. The **Kind** property indicates the type of activation event. This example is set up to handle [Protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind#Protocol) activation events.

So you could get your parameter in `eventArgs.Uri.AbsolutePath`.

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
  {
      if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
      {
         ProtocolActivatedEventArgs eventArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
         var parm = eventArgs.Uri.AbsolutePath;
         // TODO: Handle URI activation
         // The received URI is eventArgs.Uri.AbsoluteUri
      }
   }
```